# C# Assembly Problem for loading

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection

I have a project that uses assembly to load some clases dynamicly nevertheles there is this one class that the current project does not have it as a reference so when i try tu use GetType(type) i just get a null.... what's the bes approach to handle this

should i reference the projects?

Comment: Referencing is not required. Can you share code? So that some can have a look one that.

Comment: it seems that it is required i think that it needs to be in the same assembly i just have a referncy spagetti there....!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're either failing to load the assembly or the typename is incorrect. Verify that your target assembly doesn't have other dependencies that you're missing.

Comment: what do you mean with "Verify that your target assembly doesn't have other dependencies that you're missing."

Comment: Assemblies can depend on other assemblies.  If the assembly that you're trying to load the type from can't be loaded because it's missing a dependency, then bang, you're dead.

Comment: thanks i just did as you said load the assembly by its name and everything work perfectly thanks!!